# Adding AJAX to image inside wicket:link doesn't resolve image url correctly?

Tags: ajax, image, wicket

please, is there a way how to achieve this ?

1. static image with url defined in HTML relatively to the html page
2. adding the AJAX link to it to make some AJAX action

1st I had this:

```
<wicket:link>
    <img src="images/test.jpg">
</wicket:link>
```

-> image is found and displayed, the url was automatically resolved to :

```
<img src="resources/my.package.MyClass/images/test.jpg" >
```

2nd I added the AJAX action:

```
<wicket:link>
    <img src="images/test.jpg" wicket:id="sayHelloImage">
</wicket:link>
```

---

```
add(new AjaxLink("sayHelloImage") {

    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {             
        target.appendJavascript("alert('Hello!')");
    }
});
```

-> the result is that the action works, but the image url is no longer resolved, image is not found, the url stayed the same: 
img src="images/test.jpg" ...

I know that I can load the image dynamically from the class like this:
ResourceReference image = new ResourceReference(MyClass.class,"images/test.jpg");
but this is what I don't want to, I would prefer to set the image url in html.

Thank you,
with kind regards,

-josef-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<img> can't be used to produce a link (AjaxLink).

Try this:

```
<a wicket:id="sayHelloImage">
    <wicket:link>
        <img src="images/test.jpg">
    </wicket:link>
</a>
```